# How do I highlight fields with errors on a webform in red? (Form generated by JSP)

Tags: css, forms, jsp

In the Drupal content management system, if you submit a form with errors, such as missing required fields, the fields with errors have a red outline when the form reloads. How would I achieve the same effect on a JSP-generated form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add submit javascript function with validations, and in the case the required field is missing or have an error you add to input element css class with the following code

```
border-color: red;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. That could work, but would require duplicating our server-side validation logic. If we wanted to do the same thing but keep all validation server-side, would the best method be to do something like adding an "error" CSS class to the fields with errors and apply the CSS to the "error" class that you've given above?

Comment: Yes, I mean client side validation. Because I'm always duplicate all validation chacking on the client and on the server. 
if the form contain incorrect data (for example one of the fields is empty) you can stop it in client side and don't need to send request overwise i return from server global error validation code without detalization.